# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose that the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$ has a radius of convergence of $R\in (0,\infty)$. How can we find the radius of convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n^2}$$

Comment: By coming back to the definition of the radius of convergence of the series $\sum b_nz^n$ as the unique $R_b$ in $[0,+\infty]$ such that $|b_n|r^n\to0$ for every $r<R_b$ and $|a_n|r^n$ is unbounded for every $r>R_b$.

Comment: Let $b_n=0$ if $n$ is not a perfect square and $b_{n^2}=a_n$. What does the root test tell you?

Comment: Is this from an analysis course, (in which you've already completed calculus) or did you encounter this in a second semester calculus course.  It helps us to know these sorts of things in order to better help you, user19289.

Comment: @amWhy It's for an analysis course